# AspNetCore Health Check UI endpoint resolving

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kubernetes-health-check

in my .NET5 API I added Health Check UI.
In `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddHealthChecks();
services.AddHealthChecksUI(opt =>
        {
            opt.SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds(15); //time in seconds between check
            opt.MaximumHistoryEntriesPerEndpoint(60); //maximum history of checks
            opt.SetApiMaxActiveRequests(1); //api requests concurrency
            opt.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("Service", "/health");
        }).AddInMemoryStorage();
```

And finally in `Configure`:

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions
                {
                    Predicate = _ => true,
                    ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
                });
                endpoints.MapHealthChecksUI();
            });
```

But reported status is invalid and with JSON error:
[HealthCheckUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vQko.png)

Whilst going manually to endpoint (/health) I get response:

```
{"status":"Healthy","totalDuration":"00:00:00.0032081","entries":{}}
```

What I am doing wrong here? :/ I tried to look up this issue, but no solution fixed my issue. Do I really have to use absolute URLs for this?

```
GetHealthReport threw an exception when trying to get report                                                  
from /health configured with name Service.
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character 
encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? I use your code it works.

Comment: Could specify what could be of interest to you? @Chen

Comment: A minimal reproducible example. @Edvardas Alaburda I don't get this error using the code you have provided so far.

Comment: I can reproduce this UI issue with your code on a project with the settings:
net7.0
AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Oracle 6.0.3
AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI 6.0.5
AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client 6.0.4
AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.InMemory.Storage 6.0.5
Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks 7.0.7

As a result, instead of seeing the health checks, I see one single line with the following description error: "'<' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."